# Error using reference commands \ref or \eqref in subsections

Tags: equations, cross-referencing

[image]

I cannot reference correctly whenever I am in the subsection-level. The first reference to "equation of motion, 4.1" is fine, but the next reference, i.e. "Rearranging (4.1.3)" is supposed to be "Rearranging (4.11)".

Here's a code snippet:

```
\begin{equation} 
(Ms^2+Cs+K)X(s)=F(s) 
\end{equation} \label{eq:modal11} 
Rearranging \eqref{eq:modal11} yields:
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please post the code that gives rise to the problem you wish to fix. My hunch is that the problem is related to either missing or mis-placed `\label` instructions. The only way to verify (or disprove...) such a hunch is to see the actual LaTeX code.

Comment: begin{equation}
(Ms^2+Cs+K)X(s)=F(s)
\end{equation}
\label{eq:modal11}

Rearranging \eqref{eq:modal11} yields:

Comment: so you have `\label` outside the equation so it is labelling the current section

Comment: I just realized that myself. Cant believe I just spent about an hour troubleshooting and almost gave up

Comment: I've posted an answer, both to (re)state the main recommendation and to provide an explanation of why it matters where a `\label` directive is placed.

Answer (score 2):

(posting this answer mainly so that it can be checked off as having been answered)

To start off, here's a recreation of the relevant part of your screenshot, with the cross-reference pointing to the subsection header instead of to the preceding equation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}    % for "\eqref" macro
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
%%% Just to recreate the OP's setup:
\setcounter{chapter}{4}    \refstepcounter{section}
\setcounter{subsection}{2} \setcounter{equation}{10}
\subsection{Here we go} % create a dummy subsection-level header
\label{sec:herewego}

\noindent
Assuming the initial conditions to be zero yields:
\begin{equation} 
(Ms^2+Cs+K)X(s)=F(s) 
\end{equation}  \label{eq:modal11}%% "\label" outside equation env.
Rearranging \eqref{eq:modal11} yields:
\end{document}
```

---

As David Carlisle has observed in a comment, the problem arises because you placed the equation-specific `\label` instruction *outside* the `equation` environment. Sure enough, moving the `\label` instruction *inside* the `equation` environment -- say, immediately after `\begin{equation}` -- and recompiling twice yields the desired outcome as far as the cross-reference is concerned:

[image]

---

You may ask, "why is it necessary to place the equation-related `\label` instruction *inside* the `equation` environment?" To answer this question, it's necessary to take a closer look at how LaTeX's `\label`-`\ref` mechanism works.

- The `\label`-`\ref` mechanism works by `\label` latching on to an internal, low-level LaTeX macro called `\@currentlabel`. LaTeX associates this macro with the counter variable that was most recently incremented via a `\refstepcounter` instruction. As its name suggests, `\refstepcounter` not only increments a counter variable but does so in a way that "wakes up" the `\@currentlabel` macro if a `\label` instruction is issued.
- Importantly, not all counter-incrementing actions are created equal in terms of their global reach within the document. Some counters -- mainly those associated with `\chapter`, `\section`, `\subsection` etc sectioning commands -- are visible globally, in the sense that `\@currentlabel` remains associated with those counters at the global, i.e., document-wide, level until `\@currentlabel` is modified once more (most likely via a `\label` instruction).
- In contrast, other counter variables -- notably, those associated with `equation`, `theorem`, `figure`, and `table` environments -- are incremented inside their respective environments. (Aside: In `figure` and `table` environments, the counter variable is incremented by the `\caption` instruction. That's why it's necessary to place the `\label` instruction *after* the `\caption` instruction for these two environments.) One might regard these counters as being "local" to their respective environments. If a `\label` instruction is encountered inside these environments, the `\@currentlabel` macro will latch on to the intended counter, and all is well as far as the `\label`-`\ref` mechanism is concerned.
- In contrast, if the `\label` instruction isn't run until after the LaTeX environment has ended, LaTeX no longer "knows" which counter, if any, was incremented most recently inside that environment. Therefore, when the `\label` instruction is run, `\@currentlabel` gets associated with the most-recently labelled "global" counter variable; in the case of your sample document, that happens to be the `subsection` counter. (Aside: If, in the example code shown above, one were to delete the `\subsection` instruction and recompile twice, one would find that the cross-reference now points to the section-level counter ("4.1").)

What's the moral of this story? If one employs LaTeX environments (e.g., `equation` and `theorem`) which increment counter variables and wishes to cross-reference them, one must place the `\label` instruction *inside* those environments.